# Routing table troubles with vpnc on Debian

Tags: debian, vpnc

I am trying to use vpnc to wirelessly connect to a VPN network on Debian Wheezy (testing). Making sure that `wlan0` is up, I am able to establish a connection and maintain it for a minute or two. During this time, `route` shows a `default` destination bound to `tun0`. Trouble is that soon enough another default entry will crop up, pointing to `wlan0`. As far as I can tell, the vpnc prefers `tun0`, but `wlan0` precedes it in the routing table. The VPN client itself seems to handle stuff correctly, but is then surprised by something dynamic happening. How can I stop `wlan0` from hijacking the default entry in the routing table?

Similarly, I would like to be able to permanently send network interfaces down. However, as often as I do `ifconfig eth0 down`, it will always come up again after a few minutes. The same goes for `wlan0`, which usually is accompanied by `wlan0:avahi`. What are daemons that would do this kind of mischief? How do I turn them off to gain full control over my network interfaces?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think I got it. I installed `wicd` a while ago, which manages network interfaces and overrides `ifconfig` and friends. If inexplicable things happen in a daemonised way on your machine, have a look at `/etc/init.d`, e.g. `grep` all files in it like so:

```
grep 'Short-Description' /etc/init.d/*
```

Then use `update-rc.d` or `rcconf` to remove the daemon or uninstall the corresponding package, as I did with `wicd`.
Done!